# -ms-touch-action:none broken?

Tags: css, touch, internet-explorer-10

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,"/>
<style type="text/css">
    html, *, body, div, table {
        -ms-touch-action:none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Above is the markup I have tried to get IE 10 to stop zooming every time the customers press the same place on the page fast. I am using IE 10 on Windows 8. This is the only combination I am concerned with. I have a few questions:

1. Is there a way to disable double-tap-zoom?
2. Do I have to use JavaScript?
3. Do I need reference material?
4. Is this an IE bug?

Comment: This work has been delayed, for now. The CSS seems to be removed after processing, so we have bigger problems.

Comment: The problem was that we were using an old document mode for IE 10. I think we were using quirks mode. But now we have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to disable the double-tap zoom:

-ms-content-zooming: none;

Comment: [-ms-content-zooming from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I'll try it ASAP thanks.

Comment: This didn't work for us because we were using an old browser mode, IE 5 I think. We now use more JavaScript in place of DevExpress controls, and we use standards mode. Work is progressing.